# Find command windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, find

I run a command to find number of instances of a string in file:

```
find /c /i "pass" result.txt
```

The output is:

```
---------- RESULT.TXT: 6
```

How can I remove `---------- RESULT.TXT:` so that I have only the number `6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the file name as an argument, create a input redirection

```
find /c /i "pass" < result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output of `find` with a `for /F` loop like this:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %L in ('find /c /i "pass" result.txt') do (echo %L)
```

To use this code in a batch script, replace `%L` by `%%L`.